# Appending the line even though there is no match with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to compare two files and append another column if there is certain condition satisfied.

```
file1.txt

1 101 111 . BCX 123
1 298 306 . CCC 234
1 299 305 . DDD 345



file2.txt

1 101 111 BCX P1@QQQ
1 299 305 DDD P2@WWW
```

The output should be:

```
1 101 111 . BCX 123;P1@QQQ
1 298 306 . CCC 234
1 299 305 . DDD 345;P2@WWW
```

What I can do is, to only do this for the lines having a match:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$5; next }{ s=SUBSEP; k=$1 s $2 s $3 s $5  }k in a{ print $0,a[k] }' file2.txt file1.txt 
1 101 111 . BCX 123 P1@QQQ
1 299 305 . DDD 345 P2@WWW
```

But then, I am missing the second line in file1.

How can I still keep it even though there is no match with file2 regions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print every line, you need your print command not to be limited by your condition.

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
  a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$5; next
}
{
  s=SUBSEP; k=$1 s $2 s $3 s $5
}
k in a {
  $6=$6 ";" a[k]
}
1' file2.txt file1.txt
```

The `1` is shorthand that says "print every line". It's a condition (without command statements) that always evaluates "true".

The `k in a` condition simply replaces your existing 6th field with the concatenated one. If the condition is not met, the replacement doesn't happen, but we still print because of the `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$NF;next} (($1,$2,$3,$5) in a){print $0";"a[$1,$2,$3,$5];next} 1' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 101 111 . BCX 123;P1@QQQ
1 298 306 . CCC 234
1 299 305 . DDD 345;P2@WWW
```

Comment: But still, with this, I am losing the line "1 298 306 . CCC 234"

Comment: @bapors, not sure if output was edited or I missed at that time, please check now and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk '     {t=5-(NR==FNR); k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $t} 
    NR==FNR {a[k]=$NF; next} 
    k in a  {$0=$0 ";" a[k]}1' file2 file1

1 101 111 . BCX 123;P1@QQQ
1 298 306 . CCC 234
1 299 305 . DDD 345;P2@WWW
```

last component of the key is either 4th or 5th field based on first or second file input; set it accordingly and use a single `k` variable in the script.  Note that

`t=5-(NR==FNR)`

can be written as conventionally,

`t=NR==FNR?4:5`